# js timezone - incorrect day getting

Tags: javascript, datapicker

I have problem with boostrap- datepicker. The core of my problem in such example

```
var array = [2017, 12, 27];
var date = new Date(array);
console.log(date);
//Wed Dec 27 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (winter))
var day =  date.getUTCDate();
console.log(day);
//26  -> I WANT 27
console.log(month);
//11  -> I WANT 12
console.log(year);
//2017
```

As you can see at the end i get 26 (the day what i need is 27) and 11 (the month what i need is 12).
How can i change this code (remove my timezone) to get 27, 12, 2017

Comment: It's not the problem you're having, but note that the `Date` constructor doesn't accept an array. So the array is getting converted to a string, which means you're really doing `new Date("2017,12,27")` -- which is not a format that the spec says is supported (I'm quite surprised, actually, that it works on Chrome). If you have the parts like that, use the multi-argument `Date` constructor: `new Date(2017, 12 - 1, 27)`. But again, it's not the problem. It might be the *next* problem. :-)

Comment: Where are `month` and `year` coming from?

Comment: it is editable js widget with date-picker

Comment: When you do getUTCMonth() you will get a 0 based month (ie. 0 through 11). You will have to increment it to get the month (ie. add 1).

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems you're running into:

1. The difference between your timezone (GMT+0300) and UTC means that midnight December 27th 2017 in your timezone is 9p.m. December **26th** 2017 UTC.
2. I'm assuming you got `month` via `getUTCMonth`. Month values start with 0 = January, which is why you're getting 11.

To get midnight December 27th 2017 in a `Date`, use `Date.UTC`:

```js
var dt = new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 12 - 1, 27));
console.log(dt.getUTCDate());      // 27
console.log(dt.getUTCMonth() + 1); // 12
console.log(dt.getUTCFullYear());  // 2017
```

Note the `+ 1` after `getUTCMonth`, since again, month numbers are 0 = January through 11 = December.

Comment: So how can i decide the first problem?

Comment: @johnwwwin: I don't understand what you mean. The above handles both problems.